# Proving the powers of a element are all distinct.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

In a Abstract Algebra textbook of "Dummit and Foote" , There is a Group theory problem at 1.32 . The Problem goes like this :

*"If $x$ is an element of finite order $n$ in $G$, prove that the elements $1$ , $x$ , $x$<sup>$2$</sup> , $x$<sup>$3$</sup> , $x$<sup>$4$</sup> , ..... , $x$<sup>$(n-1)$</sup> are all distinct.Deduce that  $|x|$ $\le$ $|G|$. "*

**My Attempt**: Lets say there is two numbers $a$ and $b$  and they follow this inequality:

$0$ $\le$ $a$ $\lt$ $b$ $\le$ $(n-1)$

Lets assume that:
$x$<sup>$a$</sup> = $x$<sup>$b$</sup>
$\rightarrow$ $x$<sup>$(b-a)$</sup>  $=$ $1$
$\rightarrow$ $x$<sup>$(b-a)$</sup>  $=$ $x$<sup>$n$</sup>

So , $(b-a) = n$

On the other hand , From the inequality , I can deduce that $(b-a)$ $\lt$ $n$  ,Which is a contradiction .So , $x$<sup>$a$</sup> $\neq$ $x$<sup>$b$</sup>

On the other hand , if $|x|$ $>$ $|G|$ , Then $x$ can generate more distinct elements than the Group even has , which is never possible .So , $|x|$ $\le$ $|G|$.

**Confusion:** First of all , The question is unclear for me if I choose the order of $x$ to be $0$ or $1$.Because if $|x|$ is $0$ or $1$ , then ,  $x = e$ and all powers of $e$ are the same ($e$).  The problem doesn't tell me what values of $n$ I am restricted to.Can someone tell me what that is?

Also , My attempt seems to be very hand wavy .Is there a way to write the proof with **Formal logic in a rigorous manner** and **where are the major flaws of my proof?**. (I am asking this because in the future , I want to learn how to write proper proofs and learn Formal logic).

Comment: How do you define the order of a group element?

Comment: You seem to be using a fact like "if $x^c=x^d$ then $c=d$. But this fact is not correct in a general group: $x^0=x^n=x^{2n}$ in this case, for example. Also, your proposed proof uses the fact that $x^n$ is the identity, but it doesn't use the fact that $n$ is the order of $x$; put another way, your proposed proof wouldn't change if $n$ were replaced by $100n$, so there must be something wrong. Instead of going to $x^{b-a}=x^n$, just stop at $x^{b-a}=1$ and think what that implies for the order of $x$.

Comment: I didn't wanted to say that x^n is the identity ,but n is the smallest integer for which x^n = 1 is true and I deduced it from the fact that |x| = n(n is the order of x).Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: _"You seem to be using a fact like "if x^c=x^d then c=d. But this fact is not correct in a general group"_ .You are right .That is a major flaw of my proof .

Comment: $x^{b-a} = x^n$ does not imply $b-a = n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to prove that distinct powers correspond to distinct elements, you aim to get a contradiction by assuming $\exists a,b, 0\le a<b\le n-1$, such that $x^a=x^b$. This is indeed the case, because this latter would mean that $\exists l(:=b-a), 0<l\le n-1$, such that $x^l=1$, against the minimality of $n$ (by definition of *order of an element*).

Now, by closure axiom, $\langle x\rangle :=\{1,x,\dots,x^{n-1}\}\subseteq G$, whence $|x|:=|\langle x\rangle|\le |G|$.

Answer (score 1):

> "If x is an element of finite order n in G, prove that the elements 1 , x , x2 , x3 , x4 , ..... , x(n−1) are all distinct. Deduce that |x| ≤ |G|. "

Let's assume that for some two elements $x^a,x^b$ in x's cyclic group (where $0\leq a<b\leq n$) , $x^a=x^b$.

1. if $a=0$: by the assumption and definition of the first element in a cyclic group, $x^a=x^b=1$. Therefore (by definition of a finite cyclic group), we find our cyclic group is of size $b-1<b\leq n \rightarrow |x|<n$, while by definition, $|x|=n$, a contradiction.
2. else ($a>0$): we have a cyclic sub-group $AB=\{x^a,x^{a+1},...,x^{b-1}\}$, and since $0<a<b\leq n$, none of our elements in the cycle contain an identity element, meaning it's an infinite cyclic group. And since $AB \subset X$, we find that x too is of infinite order, a contradiction to the definition that x is of a finite order.

Therefore, the initial assumption, namely that X contains two identical elements in its cyclic group, is false.
**Conclusion (1):** X's cyclic group elements $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,.....,x^{(n−1)}$ are all distinct. $\blacksquare$

From here, assume $|x|>|G|$. Remember that for every elem $a\in x, a\in G$.
By the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), x's cyclic group must contain at least one identical pair of values from G, in contradiction to proof (1). Therefore, our initial assumption must be false.
**Conclusion (2): $|x|\leq |G| \blacksquare$**